# How to replace occurence of a character in a string except the first one

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

What I am trying to do is find question marks in a string and replace it with `&` except the first one. My code so far:

```
$str = 'www.domain.com?adult=2&airport=40-48?destination=recko';        
    echo preg_replace(array('/[?]/'), '&', $str );
```

output:

```
www.domain.com&adult=2&airport=40-48&destination=recko
```

How can I ignore the first occurence of the `?`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Match the start of the string up to the first `?` and use a `(*SKIP)(*F)` to omit the first match:

```
$str = 'www.domain.com?adult=2&airport=40-48?destination=recko';        
echo preg_replace('/^[^?]*\?(*SKIP)(*F)|[?]/', '&', $str );
// => www.domain.com?adult=2&airport=40-48&destination=recko
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/Pks2aN)

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of a string
- `[^?]*` - 0+ characters other than `?` as many as possible
- `\?` - a literal `?`
- **`(*SKIP)(*F)` - two PCRE verbs making the regex engine omit the text matched so far in the current iteration**
- `|` - or
- `[?]` - a literal `?`

**Alternative to `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` is to use `preg_replace_callback` and the former pattern with the first alternative branch inside capturing parentheses**:

```
$str = 'www.domain.com?adult=2&airport=40-48?destination=recko';        
echo preg_replace_callback('/^([^?]*[?])|[?]/', function($m) {
    return !empty($m[1]) ? $m[1] : "&";
}, $str );
```

See [this IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/mdUp4G)

The `^([^?]*[?])` part matches the string part from the start will the first `?` and places into Group 1. Inside the anonymous method where we pass the match object (`$m`), we can check if the group matched ("participated in the match") with the help of `!empty($m[1])`. If it is, we just put it back. If not, the `[?]`, the second branch matched, so, we replace it.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: very nice explanation

Comment: If you want, you may read more on [`*(SKIP)(*FAIL)` here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex)

Answer (score 1):

We just loop thought the whole string to find the first ? and replace every other with &. No need to use regex which is slow

```
<?php
$str = 'www.domain.com?adult=2&airport=40-48?destination=recko';     

$strlen = strlen($str);
$passed_first = false;

for($i = 0; $i < $strlen; $i++) {
    if($str[$i] == "?") {
        if(!$passed_first) {
            $passed_first = true;
        } else {
            $str[$i] = "&"; 
        }
    }
}

echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not know if it's the cleanest way, but would work and it's easy:

```
echo substr($str,0,1) . preg_replace(array('/[?]/'), '&', substr($str,1));
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be I think is do `explode("?",$str)` or `explode("&",$str)` and put them in a Array and do `preg_replace()` with small if condition where you take the first `?` and rest you ignore and do `array_marge()`.

try it and let me know

Answer (score 0):

See documentation on [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

With this you can easily extract parts of the url and do string replace only on a component that interests you

```
<?php

$str = 'www.domain.com?adult=2&airport=40-48?destination=recko';

$url = parse_url($str);
$url['query'] = str_replace('?', '&', $url['query']);

echo $url['path'] . '?' . $url['query'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) together with [`\K`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K)

```
$str = preg_replace('/(?<=\?)[^?]*\K\?/', "&", $str);
```

The lookbehind is used to require a `?` before the one to be matched. `[^?]` matches any character, that is not a `?` ([negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)). `\K` resets beginning of the reported match.

[Demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rV7xF3/1) or [PHP demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/593371)

---

Or by using a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) instead of `\K`: [`(?<=\?)([^?]*)\?` and replace with `$1&`](https://regex101.com/r/pY1bT3/1)